# greping files question

Tags: grep

I've been using grep to run a few PII scans and while it's finding results, it's indeed finding too many false positives.

Is there a way that I can tell grep not to trigger a match for a file unless it contains other data?

For instance, can I tell it not to trigger an alert on a regex for a SSN unless the file includes text like "ssn" or "social security number" somewhere else in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -lZ ssn files_to_search | xargs -0 grep what_to_search_for
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just pipe the first output to another grep.  Grep for foo and then grep for bar, so your output will only be lines that have both foo **AND** bar.

```
grep SSN filename.txt | grep -e "ssn|social security number"
```

This only hits on uppercase SSN, then passes any lines with either sss OR social security number. lower case.  Add -i for any case. If you reall want both SSN and ssn try this;

```
grep -i SSN filename.txt | grep social.security.number
```

Another one I like is to only shows lines that *don't* have bar.  Do Grep for foo then grep -v bar. Only lines with foo, that also do **not** have bar.  Using GNU grep 2.5.4 in [windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Comment: The OP said "somewhere else in the file" not "on the same line".

Comment: how far away? You can set 10 lines before and 3 lines after, or on a file by file basis. Grep lets you set a window around the mask. What do you need?

Comment: Pretty much anywhere in the file.